# showing relating records in website using mysql / php

Tags: php, mysql

Sorry for my lack of experience, but I try to explain my goal the best a can...

I have 2 MySQL tables with the following fields...

**tbl_cars_clients**
FIELDS
"client_name,
logo_img,
phone,address,email"

**tbl_cars_items**
FIELDS
"car_name,
client_name,cars_img"

---

> I have a main page called **index.php** that contains the following code

```
$query_cake = mysql_query("select * from tbl_cars_clients", $connection);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query_cars)) {


echo "<a href=\"brochures\items-cars.php?id={$row['client_name']}\"><img class='img' src={$row['ad_img']} width='350px' height='225px'></a>";
```

> I have another page called **items-cars.php**

```
<?php
                        if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
                        $client_id = $_GET['id'];
                        $query1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_cars_items WHERE client_name =  '$client_id'", $connection);
                        while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($query1)) {
                            ?>    

<?php echo "$row1['cars_img']} width='250px' height='250px'>";?>
```

On **index.php**, When I click on any of these Image hyperlinks, it opens **items-cars.php** and only display records with the same **client_name** field from the 2 tables.

My goal is to not only show the relating records on **items-cars.php**, but to display the records from the tbl_cars_clients table.

**EXAMPLE:** If I click image hyperlink for TOYOTA on **index.php**, It currently opens up the following records on **items-cars.php**...

COROLLA,
PRIUS,
CAMRY,
TUNDRA,

**Instead, I would like it to display results like...**

TOYOTA

888-123-4567

123 Maple Dr.

info@toyota.com

COROLLA,
PRIUS,
CAMRY,
TUNDRA,

Comment: The best practice is to provide a id field which is the primary key of the table and pass it to hyper link instead of passing the names. And use that id as the foreign key in tbl_cars_items.

Comment: First of all your table structure is not normalized. Please do that first Jeff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you want this...

```
<?php
                        if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
                        $client_id = $_GET['id'];
                        $query1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_cars_items WHERE client_name =  '$client_id'", $connection);
                        while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($query1)) {
$query2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_cars_clients WHERE client_name =  '$client_id'", $connection);
$row2 = mysql_fetch_array($query2);
                            ?>    
<?php echo $row2['client_name']; ?><br />
<?php echo $row2['phone']; ?><br />
<?php echo $row2['address']; ?><br />
<?php echo $row2['email']; ?><br />
<?php echo "$row1['cars_img']} width='250px' height='250px'>";?>
}
```

Comment: Thanks Qaisar. You did it. Much appreciated.